# How to determine which date is on friday?

Tags: javascript, date

I have two dropdownlists - one for year and one for weeks. How to determine the chosen weeks date should be the friday. So for example I chose week 34 and year 2011 then I should know the date on friday, in format like this: 2011-08-23. 
And preferably in javascript too.

Answer (score 8):

Use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It is quite handy for any date-related Javascripting.

Examples from their site:

```
// What date is next thrusday?
Date.today().next().thursday();

// Add 3 days to Today
Date.today().add(3).days();

// Is today Friday?
Date.today().is().friday();

// Number fun
(3).days().ago();

// 6 months from now
var n = 6;
n.months().fromNow();

// Set to 8:30 AM on the 15th day of the month
Date.today().set({ day: 15, hour: 8, minute: 30 });

// Convert text into Date
Date.parse('today');
Date.parse('t + 5 d'); // today + 5 days
Date.parse('next thursday');
Date.parse('February 20th 1973');
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00');
```

Comment: @Matt You are bitter.  There's nothing wrong with expecting the OP to take a little initiative and learn a little something about the library before using it.  That's why they give you homework in school - to learn.

Comment: @Matt `Date.parse('week 34').set({year: 2011})` does not necessarily give you week 34 of 2011. It will get the date of the Monday of week 34 of the current year and the just change the year to 2011, giving the same date of 2011. This will probably not be on a Monday and might not be in week 34.

Comment: I consider a down-vote very bad form *IF* you also answered the question yourself and the answer you are voting-down is not completely out to lunch. It shows a certain level of immaturity.

Answer (score 1):

Given a recent version (from SVN) of [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), the following will give you what you seek.

```
function date_of_friday(year, week) {
    return Date.parse(year + "-01-01").setWeek(week).next().friday();
}
```

As shown below, this gives the correct answer for your example as well as for the case when the first day of the year is in week number 1 and the case when it is not (week number 1 is the week containing the first Thursday of the year, according to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

```
date_of_friday(2011, 34); // Fri Aug 26 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CET)
date_of_friday(2011, 1);  // Fri Jan 07 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
date_of_friday(2013, 1);  // Fri Jan 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a smaller 'library':

```
Date.fromWeek= function(nth, y, wkday){
    y= y || new Date().getFullYear();
    var d1= new Date(y, 0, 4);
    if(wkday== undefined) wkday= 1;
    return d1.nextweek(wkday, nth);
}
Date.prototype.nextweek= function(wd, nth){
    if(nth== undefined) nth= 1;
    var incr= nth < 0? 1: -1,
    D= new Date(this), dd= D.getDay();
    if(wd== undefined) wd= dd;
    while(D.getDay()!= wd) D.setDate(D.getDate()+ incr);
    D.setDate(D.getDate()+ 7*nth);
    return D;
}
// test case
var dx= Date.fromWeek(34, 2011, 5);
alert([dx.getFullYear(), dx.getMonth()+1, dx.getDate()].join('-'));
/*returned value: (String) 2011-8-26*/
```